# i don't know how to change host iD for matlab 2014a on ubuntu

Tags: matlab

License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -8
Make sure the HostID of the license file matches this machine, and that the HostID on the SERVER
line matches the HostID of the license file.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2014a/8

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
License path: /root/.matlab/R2014a_licenses:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/licenses/license.dat:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a
/licenses/license_amer-Lenovo-G50-80_161052_R2014a.lic 
Licensing error: -8,523.